# Using the random function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, random

Here is the function I am working with and the main code that requires the return value:

```
def evilSetup():
"""takes a list of words of random length and places them into a dictionary based on the position of the chosen letter.Randomly selects a word from the key with the most words."""
    words = setUp()
    result = {}
    char = input('Please enter your one letter guess: ')
    for word in words:
        key = ' '.join(char if c == char else '-' for c in word)
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = []
        result[key].append(word)
    return max(result.items(), key=lambda keyValue: len(keyValue[1]))

from collections import defaultdict
import random
words= evilSetup()#list of words from which to choose
won, lost = 0,0 #accumulators for games won, and lost
while True:
    wrongs=0 # accumulator for wrong guesses
    secretWord = random.choice((words)[1])
    print(secretWord) #for testing purposes
```

What I am trying to do is have the secretWord variable in main code store a random word from the return value in evilSetup(). From a previous post I learned that I can return a random word  in the function directly using:

```
return random.choice(max(result.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[1]))[1])
```

I need to basically do this same operation, but have it stored in the secretWord variable so that the word will actually be chosen at random with each new game instead of keeping the same word chosen by the evilSetup() function.

Answer (score 0):

For reference and future use I did figure out how to do this. I was just using incorrect syntax. Here is the line of code that works properly:

```
secretWord = random.choice((words[1]))
```

It now generates a random word from the words corresponding to the dictionary key in the first position.